# Transformers Wiring To outlet cord

Tags: electrical

Can I wire a transformer to an outlet cord rather than hard wiring into hvac system. Adding a GPS to air handler and it requires its own transforme. Any suggestions??

Comment: First, why can't you hard wire it? Second, how does an air handler benefit from the global positioning system?

Comment: I took gps to mean a small ethernet appliance. There would be the well known pain to get a wall wart into a tight space. So rather than use an extention cord, and connect the wall wart to it, he was thinking about just connecting the transformer directly to a plug. Ironically, I was jumped on for suggesting he use part of an extension cord for a plug and cable, after cutting off the female end, and he was trying to avoid using an extension cord on a full time basis. I have found that often buying an extension cord, and cutting off the female makes for a quality, molded plug and cable.

Comment: I can understand if you rather assemble and use separate parts to create this assembly, but to me it is cost effective and it removes another connection point, as well as a chance to make an error. I also understand how it can make one feel good to correct the perceived basic error of another. It can also feel good to attempt to understand what someone who does not understand some technical terms, such as ethernet vs. gps, and gently teach someone that is asking a question in sincerity, about things he or she is trying to learn. To each their own.

Comment: My answer should also be downvoted some more, due to my suggestion of using a romex clamp instead of the proper cable gland for entry into the electrical box. I looked at both home depot and lowes websites, and it seems they do not carry cable glands. Rather than suggesting that the proper part be ordered, I provided incorrect information. I understand my failing in this, and will accept any point penalty that the considers fair for this failure to provide completely accurate information.  Thank you

Answer (score -3):

No problem, only question is how good you want it to look

Doorbell transformer, made to order has connector to go into an electrical junction box.

Head to home depot, or lowes - find an electrical box you like, plastic, weatherproof, metal and a cover plate for it

Add a doorbell transformer

A small pack of romex connectors (nmb might be the name on them)

a couple of wire nuts, yellow

A round extension cord that appeals to you.

Cut off the female end of the cord, and assemble as it appeals

Comment: You cannot use extension cords as fixed wiring. See [this answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/7683/33) for details.

Comment: I did not suggest the use of an extension cord for fixed wiring. I suggested the use of an extension cord as a source of a plug and cord.

Comment: Regardless of the application, I do not believe per NEC that any extension cord (or its parts) should be used after destruction, modification, etc. Basically, use it as intended, or build it from approved components.

Comment: A more than reasonable thought NEC or no NEC. It could lead to an easy path for someone to start the foolish practice of using cords that are just 'a little broken.' And that alone is worth never even putting the thought into the mind of another. Safety is not worth a few $