# Running circuit and service panel ground wire adjacent to one-another

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

My electrical service entrance is on the opposite side of the house from the municipal water supply's copper pipe, so the panel ground wire runs about 30-40 feet through the house before it's bonded to the city copper.

Is there any problem running a 12-2 wire (120V + neutral, panel is 240V split) along the same path as the panel ground (same stud/joist holes, staples, etc.)?  Would inductance from the circuit cause any problems with GFCI receptacles in the house?

Comment: Don't hang the circuit off the ground wire.  Attach it separately. Shouldn't be an issue because current never flows on a ground, except during a ground fault.

Comment: I think if it would be a problem homes with local transformers would have a problem because the main ground is run to the service panel with the service conductors. The service conductors create the largest field that A home could create and I have never had a problem with services up to 400a and more than 100' from the house.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not.  The magnetic fields of the hot and neutral conductors should cancel each other out, as explained in [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/10802/33).