# Electric ground from another circuit

Tags: electrical

I have a circuit that has a couple outlets and they used 2 wire no grounds.
Can I replaced the wire with 3 wire for the outlets and add new 3 prong outlets. It is a long difficut way back to my panel ground bar to run a ground wire for the two wire power source. I have another 240 circiut used for a 4' baseboard heater near my outlets. The baseboard has 3 wire and is grounded back to the panel. Can I run a green wire from the outlets to the ground wire used in the baseboard heater instead of running a seperate green wire back to the panel for the outlets ? Thanks.

Comment: Is the system non-metallic (Romex) or armored (BX)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10602/is-it-ok-to-borrow-a-ground-wire-from-a-different-circuit

Comment: Ok I have some bx cable with metal boxs ground to the panel. Could i run the ground wire to a metal box?

Comment: Please register your account and then [merge](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them so you have access to edit, comment, and accept answers on your own question. Posting multiple responses as answers can result in an automated lock that can prevent others from assisting you.

Comment: The metallic system only solves the problem if the existing box is already grounded through  the armor.

Comment: I have armored BX and the metal boxs are grounded back to the service panels. I have two service panels  100 AMP and 200 AMP for each apartment. Would it matter what panel ground is used ? THX

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid using the baseboard ground for the outlets since the baseboard is on a different breaker (circuit). Per NEC:

NEC 300.3(B) All conductors of the same circuit, including grounding and bonding conductors shall be contained in the same raceway, cable, or trench.

You can certianly replace the home run and associated branches with 3/12 (20 A) or 3/14 (15 A) depending on the circuit breaker size.

Comment: All my wiring is 12 ga and on 20 amp breakers. I won't be able to pull new romex back to the service panel for these outlets. There is sheetrock and would require alot of work.

Comment: I'm wondering what the rationale of this rule is. There's an exception for retrofitting ungrounded circuits that you can use a separate ground though I think that you must tie it to the breaker panel, or elsewhere in the same circuit? Must the same circuit be used so that someone doesn't get confused and remove the ground for the circuit accidentally, or is it some safety issue?

Answer (score -1):

Replacing the outlets with GFCI outlets would be an alternative solution to running a new feed.

Comment: GFCI still needs a ground, and using one from another circuit is still a bad idea.