# Adding Ground Wire to Existing NEMA 10-30 socket

Tags: wiring, grounding, 240v

I have a question about changing my 10-30 wall outlet to 14-30 for charging my EV. I thought it was a simple trip to Home Depot but it seems I may be not code compliant. I bought a Level 2, 20 amp charger, with a Nema 14-30p plug with a 25 foot cord. Clipper Creek LCS-25P level 2 charger. Reading the post below, and ArchonOSX's response in reference to the 2014 NEC, the code states a maximum cord size of 6 feet in a 250V circuit, I am clearly not compliant. So why do they sell these long EVSE chargers with these plugs? I am hoping the code has been updated. I am trying to utilize the unused garage dryer plug for my EVSE but since my garage is full of crap, I bought the larger cord length to plug my EV in the driveway.

In response to this post: [Looking for or adding a ground to an existing NEMA 10-30 socket](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/80450/looking-for-or-adding-a-ground-to-an-existing-nema-10-30-socket/80470#80470?newreg=ef0e0d4019924a7da4516d2877720985)

The 625.44 Electric Vehicle Supply Equipment Connection. section B states ALL these conditions are to be met: B1. Can be 4-wire which is NEMA 14-30 B2. EVSE fastening B3. Six foot cord length and B4. Receptable location to avoid damage to cord.

It then ends with:

All other electric vehicle supply equipment shall be permanently wired and fastened in place to the supporting surface, a wall, a pole, or other structure. The electric vehicle supply equipment shall have no exposed live parts.

Can someone advise me if I should cut the cord length to 6 feet and move my EV into the garage? I may be forced to then have to buy the $1,000 wall unit and pay an electrician to install it.

I'm trying to save the planet but it's getting expensive!

This is my first post so apologies for the length of my query. Thank you for your patience and advice.

Comment: Hello everyone. I found the answer. The code has been updated in NEC 2017. After doing some digging the permanent fastening of portable equipment and restricting the length to 6 feet was unrealistic given demand for flexibility in EV charging. This link shows the rationale for update: https://www.nfpa.org/Assets/files/AboutTheCodes/70/ProposedTIA%201168_NFPA%2070.pdf And this link shows the updated code: http://mydocs.epri.com/docs/publicmeetingmaterials/1112/PDNNSH5Q3Z2/Day%201%20PlugIn%20Electric%20Vehicle%20Codes%20Standards/D1_7C%20G%20Kissel%20Article%20625%20Restructure%20Proposal.pdf

Comment: And her is the updated partial code: https://www.nfpa.org/Assets/files/AboutTheCodes/70/ProposedTIA%201168_NFPA%2070.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The cord lengths described in those documents involve **the cord between the wall and the charger**.  Looking at the item on the Web, it appears its cord is quite short, and certainly compliant.

*The 25' cord you speak of is between the charger and the car, and that's a non-factor. NEC doesn't regulate that cord nearly as much, because it protected by the charger.  NEC never intended for you to need to park the car so its port is within 6' of the charger. That would make every public charging station illegal and impossible, for Pete's sake!*

---

Retrofitting a ground wire is pretty straightforward. You can run it as a separate bare wire to any of

- back to the panel the circuit is powered from
- any junction box for any  other circuit that is grounded and comes out of that panel... however, the ground wire must be large enough, you need a 10 AWG ground, so a 12 AWG ground won't do.
- any junction box fed by non-flexible metal conduit back to that panel
- the Grounding Electrode System, i.e. The system of grounding wires that connect the service panel to the ground rod