# How can I reduce the humidity in my home?

Tags: humidity

Moisture inside my home fills up moisture bucket within a month, and the furniture and anything on the ground has green mildew/mold growing.

When the humidity is high the tile floors on the screened porch are completely water logged (I mean not just a little condensation, the floor looks like it is flooded).

Black mold is growing on the ceiling of the bathroom despite the window being open for ventilation.

Comment: Question #20 on this site was asked back in 2010 and referenced knob and tube wiring. Do you have a URL of the question you are referencing? http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/20/should-old-knob-and-tube-wiring-be-replaced

Comment: What is a moisture bucket?  Is your home conditioned?  Where do you live?

Comment: I live in Williston, FL - "Damp Rid" attracts moisture -

Comment: Sorry #20 is a mistake, disregard to remark. My home is has central heat and air, is that what you mean by "conditioned"? I don't keep the air on all year around, are you implying that I need to keep the air on?

Answer (score 1):

If your house is too humid, it's because too much moisture is entering it. To fix that, you need to find the source of the moisture and reduce or eliminate it.

There are lots of places the moisture could be coming from. Humid air might entering your house from your crawlspace or basement (especially if you get water pooling after heavy rains), leaks in your roof, or leaky pipes are all common causes.

Comment: You are exactly right, this house is 67 years old and it is block with tile floors thru out. Humid air comes through the windows because I open them everyday - are you saying that I should not? Also I believe humid air comes from the ground under the house and tile. What can I do?

Comment: I gather you aren't using an air conditioner, in which case, I don't think air coming in the windows is the problem; it's not so humid there that it would never dry out (the weather forecast for the next week doesn't put the dew point above 50f, which is only 40% humidity at 70 degrees); if the source of humidity is something else, then the ventilation helps. I could be wrong though.

Comment: And I'm not sure what you mean by "it is block"; if you've got slab on grade (no basement or crawlspace) with tile floors, I think the moisture intake would be slow enough that ventilation could compensate for it - I suspect the condensation problem is because the floor is cooler, not because it's the source of the moisture.. but it's hard to say for sure.

Answer (score -2):

Jesus, don't breath too deep, LOL.

The problem is your house is too cold, so it is causing excessive condensation.

So, your choices are either to turn the heat up and make the house a lot warmer, like 80-degrees +...

Or you can get an industrial strength, whole-house dehumidifier, and I can tell you that thing will suck down electricity like nobody's business. You will have the Feds raiding you because they think are running a grow house if you install one of those things.

Another strategy would be to use better air management. The idea is to restrict the flow of air into the house. For this to work you have to have a really tightly sealed house, so if it is not new construction you can forget this. If it IS new construction, try to find out where air is infiltrating and carefully control it and dehumidify it.

Comment: I live in Florida, it is humid all the time - I can't leave my heater on when the air outside is hotter than it is inside.

Comment: If you are getting condensation, I outlined your options. If you want to live in a refrigerator with open windows you are going to get condensation.