# what 2017 NEC code talks about knob and tube replacement

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

Have an insurance job and the home owner wants to redo the 1st floor apartment. The apartment is wired with knob and tube so I recommended it needed to be updated. When pitched to the insurance company they said that would be fine, but I need to let them know where it states knob n tube needs to be replaced. I know rule of thumb is once you work on the circuit it needs to be updated I just cant find any codes to back that up. If anyone can help give me a leg up here it would be appreciated.

Comment: You're not the home owner?  Doesn't sound like a DIY question to me then.  And NEC doesn't state that knob and tube has to be updated.  An existing knob and tube system built properly in its time is entirely fine to remain in existence.

Comment: DIY isn't the rule, it's the name of the forum. The rules are about residential but do include contractors.  OP talk to your AHJ, ask them for a letter requiring the upgrade under the circumstances.

Comment: Knob and tube is still allowed and with the ability to run a separate ground if in good shape the circuits can be updated to 3 wire.

Answer (score 1):

Although what Billy says may be technically true, that doesn't mean it is not a good idea to update it. A lot of insurance company's won't insure a house with known knob and tube wiring.  The insurance company execs are not stupid.  It has nothing to do with code compliance.  They know that all k&t wiring is 70 to 80-years old and never designed to handle the loads of the modern-day house hold.   Stick with your pitch.  They don't need chapter and verse.  They just want someone who will upgrade it for a reasonable price. Good Luck. P.

Comment: Saying K&T can't handle modern loads is misleading.  If you add new circuits for new loads, the old K&T can handle what's left.  Removing K&T from lighting loads makes no sense from a safety point of view, in that lighting loads are going down with CFL and LED technology.  See also https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/20279/5960

Answer (score 0):

The requirement to replace K&T is not an NEC requirement. It's a requirement imposed by the insurance company, and/or the local government.  If you want to provide a source for the requirement, you'll have to check with the insurer and/or the local government.