# Extension Cords needed, can't find

Tags: extension-cord, extension

I have moved into an older home. All of the outlets are two prong only. Is there an extension cord that will plug into the wall with a 2 prong, but has 3 prongs in the extension part? If not, how am I going to make things work in this old place, lol?? Thank you for any help!

Comment: Is safety important to your family? There are many ways to resolve that situation safely and legally.  Wackadoodle extension cords are not one of them.

Comment: How old is it, and do you know what it was wired with? (old, likely cloth-covered NM, K&T, BX/AC, conduit)?

Answer (score 1):

You can legally change the outlet, as long as it is “GFCI Protected” and marked “No Equipment Ground".  You'll get the safety benefits of a third wire ground, though not all the surge protection benefits of your power strip.  The GFCI units do use some 'vampire' power, about 1 Watt, 24/7.

Section 406.3(D)(3) of the 2008 National Electric Code covers this situation.

[image: GFCI no equipment ground]

Consider also a whole house surge protector, and if you have K&T wiring, an [AFCI on the K&T](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/20279/5960).  That said, if any of this sounds unfamiliar, hire a home inspector to check out everything and provide advice as to priorties.

Comment: A whole house surge protector protects *equipment* from certain types of damage. But it really doesn't do much for personal safety.

Answer (score 0):

There are adapters like this:

[image]

By screwing the green tab into the outlet faceplate, you are ***theoretically*** providing a ground.  There are also models with ground wires you can attach to known grounds like water pipes.

I would get a circuit tester like this to insure the adapter is actually safe.

[image]

Comment: Downvoted (sorry!) because cheater plugs are just that -- cheaters. It might be different in places like Chicago with tons of conduit, but I *never* find a ground on an old outlet. And I know you said to get the tester, but that's just the path to heartbreak.

Comment: Thanks for explaining your downvote.  I expected that from certain types of people.  I'm sure completely rewiring her house is a much more practical and realistic solution...OK, that was a bit sarcastic (sorry!)

Comment: Well rewiring isn't the only way to fix the situation, you can also use GFCI receps or breakers and then legally and safely convert to grounded receps. I think your answer is worthwhile though, since you specifically mention the need to verify that a ground is present.

Comment: This is better than violating an extension cord that you're likely to still have, and use, lying around after you *do* upgrade. Like that's ever going to happen anyway, +1

Comment: Do think those adapters have been illegal in Canada for years.  Someone can check and add if I am wrong.

Answer (score -1):

No, they no longer make those because they are dangerous.  What you really need to do is call in an electrician to update your wiring so that it's safe.

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't own the home and trust me she's not going to do anything to change it!

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will talk to someone at the home improvement place to try to get these items. I certainly don't want to do anything unsafe!

Comment: According to the internet these grounded plug adapters are indeed still made and available in the US. All cautions still apply.

Comment: "ground-***wire*** *style* of [cheater plug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheater_plug) was discontinued when it was noted that a loose unattached grounding wire could by accident become inserted into the "hot" ". -  However, even the type *w/o* a wire *are* "illegal in some jurisdictions, in particular throughout Canada"